# How do I fetch table data from firefox page with javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to get all table data on firefox console.I can get some span id's.But I can't access to table.I'm trying to code below.

I tried this code for get access the table.

```
var x = document.getElementById("table-positions").rows[0].cells.length;
```

But it's return `undefined`

Example:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("table-positions").rows[0].cells.length; 
console.log(x);
```

```html
<table id="table-positions" class="grid tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="provider header sorting_desc" style="display: table-cell;">Trader</th>
                <th class="header">Currency</th>
                <th class="header">Type</th>
                <th class="header-lots header">Mini Lots</th>
                <th class="header">Date opened</th>
                <th class="header">Entry</th>
                <th class="header">Stop</th>
                <th class="header">Limit</th>
                <th class="header">Current</th>
                <th class="header">Profit</th>

                <th class="last-cell-open-trades">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-body-positions"><tr class="trade p-364967">
                    <td class="provider bold" style="display: table-cell;"><a href="/trader/364967" target="_blank">WaveDrive</a></td>
                    <td>EUR/USD</td>
                    <td class="c-1">BUY</td>
                    <td>1.6</td>
                    <td><a data-action="details"><span><span class="">2019/01/04 13:36:19</span></span></a></td>
                    <td>1.13755</td>
                    <td><a data-action="update-stop" data-filter="stop" class="">1.08809 (-494.6)<br>-$791.36</a></td>
                    <td><a data-action="update-limit" data-filter="limit">1.18809 (505.4)<br>$808.64</a></td>
                    <td>1.13601</td>
                    <td class="c-1">-15.4 pips<br>-$27.04</td>
                    <td class="actions">
                        <a data-action="update-lock" class=""><span><svg class="icon-svg icon-locker-open"><use xlink:href="/Static/Images/Sprites/symbol-defs.svg?b21b2663b89c00de708b9c02ef50197996#icon-locker-open"></use></svg></span></a>
                        <a data-action="close-trade" class=""><span><svg class="icon-svg icon-x"><use xlink:href="/Static/Images/Sprites/symbol-defs.svg?b21b2663b89c00de708b9c02ef50197996#icon-x"></use></svg></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr class="trade p-364967">
                    <td class="provider bold" style="display: table-cell;"><a href="/trader/364967" target="_blank">WaveDrive</a></td>
                    <td>EUR/USD</td>
                    <td class="c-2">BUY</td>
                    <td>1.6</td>
                    <td><a data-action="details"><span><span class="">2019/01/04 13:35:17</span></span></a></td>
                    <td>1.13868</td>
                    <td><a data-action="update-stop" data-filter="stop" class="">1.08865 (-500.3)<br>-$800.48</a></td>
                    <td><a data-action="update-limit" data-filter="limit">1.18865 (499.7)<br>$799.52</a></td>
                    <td>1.13601</td>
                    <td class="c-2">-26.7 pips<br>-$45.12</td>
                    <td class="actions">
                        <a data-action="update-lock" title="Lock or unlock this trade: A locked trade will prevent the trader or Automator from sending signals for this trade. As a result this trade will only be closed if the set Stop/Limit is reached or if you close it manually!"><span><svg class="icon-svg icon-locker-open"><use xlink:href="/Static/Images/Sprites/symbol-defs.svg?b21b2663b89c00de708b9c02ef50197996#icon-locker-open"></use></svg></span></a>
                        <a data-action="close-trade" title="Close"><span><svg class="icon-svg icon-x"><use xlink:href="/Static/Images/Sprites/symbol-defs.svg?b21b2663b89c00de708b9c02ef50197996#icon-x"></use></svg></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr class="trade p-364967">
                    <td class="provider bold" style="display: table-cell;"><a href="/trader/364967" target="_blank">WaveDrive</a></td>
                    <td>EUR/USD</td>
                    <td class="c-1">BUY</td>
                    <td>1.6</td>
                    <td><a data-action="details"><span><span class="">2019/01/04 13:47:11</span></span></a></td>
                    <td>1.13715</td>
                    <td><a data-action="update-stop" data-filter="stop" class="">1.08709 (-500.6)<br>-$800.96</a></td>
                    <td><a data-action="update-limit" data-filter="limit">1.18709 (499.4)<br>$799.04</a></td>
                    <td>1.13601</td>
                    <td class="c-1">-11.4 pips<br>-$20.64</td>
                    <td class="actions">
                        <a data-action="update-lock" title="Lock or unlock this trade: A locked trade will prevent the trader or Automator from sending signals for this trade. As a result this trade will only be closed if the set Stop/Limit is reached or if you close it manually!"><span><svg class="icon-svg icon-locker-open"><use xlink:href="/Static/Images/Sprites/symbol-defs.svg?b21b2663b89c00de708b9c02ef50197996#icon-locker-open"></use></svg></span></a>
                        <a data-action="close-trade" title="Close"><span><svg class="icon-svg icon-x"><use xlink:href="/Static/Images/Sprites/symbol-defs.svg?b21b2663b89c00de708b9c02ef50197996#icon-x"></use></svg></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr class="group-provider ui-helper-hidden" id="123">
                    <td colspan="8" class="group-provider-name">
                        <div class="group-collapse section__title section__title--grey section__title--open"></div>
                        <a class="" target="_blank" href="/trader/364967">
                            <img src="/image.ashx?type=provider&amp;size=s&amp;id=364967" alt="Manual"><strong>WaveDrive</strong>
                        </a>
                        <span class="manual ui-helper-hidden"><strong>Manual</strong></span>
                        <span class="group-provider-details"><strong>3</strong> Open Positions | <strong> 4.8 </strong> Mini Lots</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="c-1">-16.3 pips<br>-$33.28</td>
                    <td>
                        <button data-action="close-all-by-provider" data-pending="false">Close All</button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="display: none"></td>

                    <td style="display: none"></td>
                    <td style="display: none"></td>
                    <td style="display: none"></td>
                    <td style="display: none"></td>
                    <td style="display: none"></td>
                    <td style="display: none"></td>
                </tr></tbody>
    </table>
```

Also same result for "table-summary-positions" table.

Here is the pic how it's looks like.

[image: dara.png]

This table dynamic and it's could be incrase or decreases row's.How do I get all data ?

Comment: Just tried the data you provided on a jsFiddle and it works - https://jsfiddle.net/9z0pydr6/

Comment: I copied your code, as-is, into a Stack Snippet and updated the question. Your code doesn't return `undefined`, it returns 11, which is the number of cells in the first row as expected. Perhaps you were running your code before the table was loaded or similar, in which case, the answer is: Wait for the table to load (lots of questions and answers here -- and elsewhere -- to show how to do that).

Comment: If you want to reliably access the table's *body* rather than its *header*, you may want `var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#table-positions > tbody > tr > td")` though.

Comment: So you loop over the table rows and read the cell's text....

Comment: How do i get the all td values ? I tried some code but it's not work.